# How can I start a simple react next application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to follow the shopify app tutorial.

https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/set-up-your-app

When I run npm run dev I am getting the following error.

```
started server on http://localhost:3000
TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined
at fileExists 
(/Users/user/projects/shopify_dev/node_modules/next/dist/lib/file- 
exists.js:1:211)
```

When I trying to initialize on a different path

```
npm init next-app
```

I am getting another error

```
npx: installed 1 in 0.814s
/Users/user/.npm/_npx/56860/lib/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js:2
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your nodejs installation to v10 or higher. That nextjs function uses the [`fs` Promises API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), which was added in node v10.